# Visa refusal under paragraph V4.2v (a) and (e)

Tags: uk

[image] in my application when send all documents to the Visa centre I included my application letter explaining why I want to join the army, army assessment letter, hotel booking document. About funds it's a self sponsor I dd add my business and regration and bank statement..IAM married with two kids I dd add there birth certificate and marriege certificate, and also add my property deed and motor blue book and my mentor letter in UK with all his iD...wat should do so that I should go and attend my assessment in UK can I appeal this ??[image]

Comment: Yes it is, please advise me on what I can do next I have spent much of my time training for this assessment and I know I will pass and I cant jst miss it like that help? I

Comment: Please edit your original question rather than creating a new question to add more detail.

Comment: @cidrickzimbiri in the UK, a business bank account is for business expenditure and its unlawful to use those funds for personal use - you need to show that this is legal in your country, that you have the legal right to use your business funds to support your trip to the UK for purposes unrelated to your business.